# Cannot MERGE clob in db2

Tags: db2, clob

I'm having an issue executing a merge statement in `DB2 (Version 11)`. The statement works fine if I ommit the "WHEN MATCHED" clause or if the "WHEN MATCHED" clause updates the timestamp column. There's an issue when I update a CLOB.

Statement:

```sql
MERGE into myTable as tab
USING (VALUES (123, '<test>data</test>', CURRENT TIMESTAMP)) as src(id, xml, tstmp)
ON tab.ID = src.id
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
      SET tab.XML = src.xml
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
      INSERT (ID, XML, CREATED_TIMESTAMP) VALUES (src.id, src.xml, src.tstmp);
```

Error:

> [Code: -907, SQL State: 27000]  An attempt was made to modify the target table, "myTable", of the MERGE statement by constraint or trigger "AFTER_UPDATE_myTable".. SQLCODE=-907, SQLSTATE=27000, DRIVER=4.22.29

I should note that I know there is only one entry in myTable where ID = 123.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[SQL0907N](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic2.html#sql0907n):

> SQL0907N
>
> An attempt was made to modify the target table, *table-name*, of the MERGE statement by constraint or trigger *name*.
>
> **Explanation**
>
> The MERGE statement caused constraint or trigger name to activate, which attempted to update, insert into or delete from table *table-name*
>   that is also a target table, or table within the same table hierarchy,
>   of the MERGE statement. This is not allowed.
>
> **User response**
>
> Change the MERGE statement to remove the operation that causes the constraint or trigger to activate, or alter the table that has the
>   constraint or trigger to remove the reference to the target table.

You probably have an after-update trigger `AFTER_UPDATE_myTable` on this table, which changes data in the same table. Modify it, for example, in such a way, that it is not activated on update of namely the column `XML` if possible.